# How can I run masonry after nivo slider is loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, nivo-slider

I try to run masonry after the nivo slider has loaded so that masonry adjusts for the image captions which I have below the images in the slider.

I tried this code, but masonry breaks when I add `container.masonry();`

```
var container = $('#container');
$('.slider').nivoSlider({
  effect: 'sliceDown',
  directionNav: false,
  pauseTime: 7000,
  afterLoad: function() {
      container.masonry();
  }
});
```

Comment: Define 'breaks'...also, try to get a jsfiddle up or at least a screenshot of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check this ,

http://www.metaphorcreations.com/nivo-slider-and-custom-links/

```
$("body").live("hover",function(){
    container.masonry();
});
```

Run `masonry` inside `hover function` of body or page top parent element..this is an small trick, it will solve this problem